# pix2pix tensorflow:UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python

This code is in https://github.com/affinelayer/pix2pix-tensorflow/tree/master/tools;

When I run it in the terminal:

```
python3 tools/process.py --input_dir mytest --operation resize --output_dir photos/resized，
```

I meet this problem:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Here's the code:

```
def resize(src):
    height, width, _ = src.shape
    dst = src
    if height != width:
        if a.pad:
            size = max(height, width)
            # pad to correct ratio
            oh = (size - height) // 2
            ow = (size - width) // 2
            dst = im.pad(image=dst, offset_height=oh, offset_width=ow, target_height=size, target_width=size)
        else:
            # crop to correct ratio
            size = min(height, width)
            oh = (height - size) // 2
            ow = (width - size) // 2
            dst = im.crop(image=dst, offset_height=oh, offset_width=ow, target_height=size, target_width=size)

    assert(dst.shape[0] == dst.shape[1])

    size, _, _ = dst.shape
    if size > a.size:
        dst = im.downscale(images=dst, size=[a.size, a.size])
    elif size < a.size:
        dst = im.upscale(images=dst, size=[a.size, a.size])
    return dst
```

Comment: Fix your indentation. What you posted here is not valid Python code.

Answer (score -1):

The obvious reason for this is that valid UTF-8 cannot ever contain a byte with a value of 0xff. I wouldn't know what part of your code is trying to read UTF-8, but whatever it tries to read, it's not UTF-8.

Comment: so what should i do??thanks,my code is in the web  https://github.com/affinelayer/pix2pix-tensorflow/tree/master/tools

Comment: maybe about this code?what should i do?? https://github.com/affinelayer/pix2pix-tensorflow/blob/master/tools/tfimage.py